# Change base64 encode inline image in email

Tags: email, inline, mailkit, mimekit

I am using MailKit and Mimekit to process emails and convert them to pdf with our tool. We are getting emails with MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient. They are working well, but.
Some emails have very large inline images, and if we convert them to pdf it could be 96MB. Thats too big for our process. So somehow we would have to decrease the size of the base64 encoded images or change them to a base64 encoded jpg (with "attachment removed" text). My problem is that the message is read only.
Is there any possibility to change the relevant base64 encoded content in these emails?

I head read mimekit and mailkit documents, searched soulion...